# Why can't my test inherit its ContextConfiguration location from its parent?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

In the interest of DRY, I want to define my ContextConfiguration in a parent class and have all my test classes inherit it, like so:

Parent class:

```
package org.my;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/org/my/Tests-context.xml")
public abstract class BaseTest {

}
```

Child class:

```
package org.my;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations = true)
public class ChildTest extends BaseTest {

    @Inject
    private Foo myFoo;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
          ...
    }
}
```

According to the [ContextConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) docs I should be able to inherit the parent's location, but I can't get it to work.  Spring is still looking for a file in the default location (`/org/my/ChildTest-context.xml`) and barfs when it can't find it. I've tried the following with no luck:

- Making the parent class concrete
- Adding a no-op test to the parent class
- adding an injected member to the parent class as well
- combinations of the above

I'm on spring-test 3.0.7 and JUnit 4.8.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the `@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations = true)` on the child class. `inheritLocations` is set to true by default.

By adding the `@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations = true)` annotation without specifying a locations ,you are telling to Spring to extended the list of resource locations by adding the default context which is `/org/my/ChildTest-context.xml`.

Try with something like this :

```
package org.my;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ChildTest extends BaseTest {

    @Inject
    private Foo myFoo;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
          ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  This reminds me, I need to go accept your other answer.  You are officially the SO MVP for this week :-)